# Определить максимальный размер шрифта для кнопки

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Есть кнопка. На разных экранах у неё разный размер, зависит от ширины экрана. 
Надо высчитать максимально возможный размер шрифта для этой кнопки.
В идеале задачу чуть сложнее. Много кнопок на экране с разной длины текстом. Найти наименьший максимальный размер для всех кнопок и применить. Чтобы везде был одинакового размера шрифт.

Comment: Можно скриншот, непонятно, что вы имеете в виду под размером шрифта.

Comment: Встает вопрос, что такое максимальный? Если это такой шрифт, при котором любая запись на кнопке умещалась в один ряд, тогда теряется смысл максимальности, как удобства для пользователя. Ведь экран может быть условно маленьким, тогда и шрифт станет маленьким и неудобным для пользователя. Не лучше ли уйти от однорядности надписи? Тогда где передел максимальности шрифта? В практике я ориентируюсь на удобный размер шрифта в sp (dp), а уже затем стремлюсь, чтобы разметка сохраняла главные свои идеи при разных длинах надписи.